# How to Create UILocalNotification for Multiple firedates

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Hi in my Application I have Multiple events for every event i need to create one `UILocalNotification` for example like I want to say wishes on Fathers day,Mothers and some festivals. So I already i have the specific date now I want to fire it on the particular day please how to do this. I have already done for single `UILocalNotification` Now I need  for multiple `firedates`.

My code.

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
  {

       NSCalendar *regCalender =[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
       NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [regCalender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

      [dateComponent setYear:2014];
      [dateComponent setMonth:7];
      [dateComponent setDay:8];
      [dateComponent setHour:15];
      [dateComponent setMinute:31];

      UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
     [dd setDate:[regCalender dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];
     UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
     [notification setAlertBody:@"Welcome"];
     [notification setFireDate:dd.date];
     [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
      notification.soundName=@"double_tone.mp3";
     [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];

  }
```

I have used this above code for single firedate UILocalNotification please tell me how to do it for multiple firedates.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to create separate `UILocalNotification` for each date.

Comment: @rckoenes can please tell how i need to create uilocalnotification for each date is the any sample for it

Comment: Serious!! You can create one `UILocalNotification` but don't understand how to create more than one? Just create an new instance of the `UILocalNotification` class, assign the correct date and schedule the `UILocalNotification`. Be aware that there is a maximum of 64 `UILocalNotification` per app.

Comment: @rckoenes i have already tried its not working

Comment: Well I do something the same and can tell you that it will work. Just create a method where you can pass the fire date and message. Let this method create the `UILocalNotification` and schedule it.

Comment: @rckoenes sorry im not able get u as im newbe for ios development i getting ur point can please give some clear view

Comment: Don't use, `setScheduledLocalNotifications:` because this will override any existing notifications. use `- (void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` to add a new notification.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer,
In compsForFireDate you can ad multiple date and you can call it yearly

```
 -(void) YearlyNotification: (int)year :(UILocalNotification *)notification : (NSDate*) alramDate
    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *compsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: alramDate];
        [compsForFireDate setHour: 10] ; //for fixing 10AM hour
        [compsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
        [compsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;
        notification.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;
        notification.fireDate=[calendar dateFromComponents:compsForFireDate];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }
```

Comment: can please tell me wt is fromdate: and alramdate where i need to give the notification message

Comment: dateFromComponents is that you have to make it in NSDateComponents *compsForFireDate , you can set there your date, hour, minute and second. and you ca give notification message by using notification.alertBody=@"Your message";

Comment: It looks like you need start by learn how to program. Because all the examples give here should get you going. You are asking very basic question which is giving me the feeling that you never wrote any code before and are just copy pasting everything together. Start reading the iOS documentation and introductions to programming.

Comment: I think user3793919 is new tO IOS , Anyway no problem do practice you will succeed.

Comment: @ArbazShaikh thanks i will try ur code let know as im new for the ios development little bit stuggling to get going

Comment: @ArbazShaikh once comeback to online please replay me

Comment: Yes How can I help you?

Comment: @ArbazShaikh can please tell is that possiable to give mutiple monhts also here

Comment: Yes you can do it for multiple months,just take another object for **NSDateComponents** And if you like the answer just raise it up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are registering the notification with [`setScheduledLocalNotifications:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications) which will replace any existing notification. This is clearly  stated in the documentation.

To schedule a single [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) use [`-(void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification%3a)

Here I have create a methods that take a date and a string to schedule an [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
-(void) addLocalNotificationForDate:(NSDate *)date withAlertBody:(NSString *)alertBody {

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [notification setAlertBody:alertBody];
    [notification setFireDate:date];
    [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    notification.soundName=@"double_tone.mp3";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: please tell how can i pass the multiple dates and message in to this method